How to implement the rendering of an object so that part of the object to the left of the other is one, and part to the right of the other
I don't even know how to formulate the question correctly. In general, there is an object (platform). There is a certain ray-a line that moves according to its own specific laws, sometimes touching the platform.
Is it possible to implement it somehow so that:

if the entire platform is to the left of the line, then the platform becomes one specific shape and a specific texture
if it is to the right, then it has a different shape and a different texture
if the line touches the platform somewhere, then the platform is already partially one and partially the other, depending on where exactly this line is located

I could roughly compare it as in some photo editors there is a slider before / after. I moved it to one side - you see the picture before the editorial office, I moved it to the other - after. Well, in the middle

You could have 2 objects as platform (sprites?) which should never overlap, and render both partially, depending on where ray is now.

Is it only a matter of what the platform looks like? I mean: you don't need the platform's collider to change its shape, do you?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As long as you only need to modify what the platform looks like, basically switching from one version of it to another version depending on the X coordinate of every pixel displayed, you could make your own shader with Shader Graph (an official Unity visual tool to create shaders).
This custom shader would set the alpha depending on the position (you can use the Position node) by comparing the position's X component (you can use the Step node) with a custom threshold float value set through a Property.
The texture etc. should also be properties of your custom shader.
You can make two versions of this shader, or just use a boolean Property to choose which version: one version sets the alpha to zero below the threshold and to one above the threshold, and another version goes the other way round.
Create the two platforms as the children of an empty GameObject, and use the custom shader to make each platform partially invisible on the right side of the threshold. Place a script in the parent GameObject that senses the "ray" and updates the threshold on both custom materials.
This official tutorial is probably enough to understand how to create your own shader with Shader Graph.
